# How can I find the fields available on a Node/Object without an Object ID?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

If I have an ID for an Object in Facebook's Graph API, I can find out all the available fields on that Node Type by setting the parameter `metadata=1`.

For example, `https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/12345?access_token=censored&metadata=1` will return all the possible fields on the *type* of object that 12345 is. If 12345 is of type `userleadgeninfo`, then this query won't return details about object 12345, it will return all available fields I can request of any type of `userleadgeninfo` object.

But if I don't have an ID, how do I know what fields are available for an object type? For example, I can see from the metadata query on a `userleadgeninfo` object that one of the fields returned is `retailer_item_id`. However, my object 12345 doesn't have one of those, so I don't have an ID I can plug into the Graph API to get the metadata available on *that* type.

Comment: _"But if I don't have an ID, how do I know what fields are available for an object type?"_ - if you don't _have_ any object to query - then what does it matter to begin with, what fields it might have?

Comment: Also, the API has documentation - for the most part, that should list what fields & edges are available, for a specific object type.

Comment: >  if you don't have any object to query - then what does it matter to begin with, what fields it might have. <br/>

Thanks, @CBroe, but you misunderstand my position. I may not have any such object in _my_ account, however, I am developing an app for thousands of Facebook users, many of whom do have such an ID in their accounts and workflows.

Comment: "the API has documentation - for the most part, that should list what fields & edges are available, for a specific object type."  

This is untrue. Consider the [documentation for the lead gen data object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/lead-gen-data). It does not tell me about the `retailer_item_id` field it provides, nor does it tell me what object type that provides me an ID to. E.g., it doesn't tell me what node type I would get if I had such an ID I could query.

Comment: Here's an example. I can get the [schema for LeadGenData here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/lead-gen-data/).  And I can [see it has a Leads edge here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/lead-gen-data/leads/), and that gives me IDs to UserLeadGenInfo nodes, but the UserLeadGenInfo node isn't documented anywhere that I can find. And what I have is a UserLeadGenInfo ID and I want to figure out where I can go from there.